# Issue with starting an activity from activityManager

Tags: android, android-view

I am working on an android project, where i have got a list view to be populated. It happens in a group activity where intent is passed to a controller and from that controller the activity starts using specified intent. 
In identifying the issue through debugging, i got that the debugger gets stuck in the line specified:

```
**View view = activityManager.startActivity(intentId, intent).getDecorView();**
```

and the list view never gets populated, however the when i check the array from which i have to populate items, that shows me that it contains the items. One interesting thing is that, when i close the application, and restart it and then see the list view, it shows up fine. This is strange for me. Why does it not show up first time and show up second time. the whole function has the following code:

```
 public void startGroupActivity(String intentId, Intent intent) {

    contentViewLayout.removeAllViews();
    Log.e("Start Group Actvity", intentId);
    View view = activityManager.startActivity(intentId, intent).getDecorView();
    contentViewLayout.addView(view, contentViewLayoutParams);
}
```

That behavior is simply un-understandable for me. Any help is appreciated.